# Error while sending the two files over the socket

Tags: java, network-programming

I am trying to send two files over the socket, but unfortunately I am getting error:

> Java.io.EOFException

I am posting the server side and client side code. Please help me to send the two files over the socket.

```
ServerSocket servsock = null; /* initilization */
Socket sock = null;
//Socket sock = null;
try {
System.out.println("waiting please connect the device");
servsock = new ServerSocket(5555); /* port number */
sock=servsock.accept();
System.out.println("waiting...");

BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);

/* read the length of the file */
long fileLength = dis.readLong();
fos = new FileOutputStream(FILE_TO_RECEIVED1);
bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

for(int j = 0; j < fileLength; j++)
bos.write(bis.read());    
bos.close();
/* once the first file is read , I  have closed the BOS */

/* code to read the second file */
long fileLength1 = dis.readLong();
fos = new FileOutputStream(FILE_TO_RECEIVED2);/* path where  
         second file should be stored  */
bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
/* read the second file  */ 
for(int j = 0; j < fileLength1; j++) 
bos.write(bis.read());

bos.close();
dis.close();
```

GUI side code 
    //code to send the two files over the socket

```
BufferedOutputStream bos = new  
BufferedOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);
System.out.println("Accepted connection : " + sock);

File myFile1 = new File (FILE_TO_SEND1);
long length = myFile1.length();
dos.writeLong(length); //sending length of the file

fis = new FileInputStream(myFile1);
bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
int theByte = 0;
while((theByte = bis.read()) != -1) bos.write(theByte); 
/*sending first file */
bis.close();
fis.close(); 
dos.close();                        

dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);

File myFile2 = new File (FILE_TO_SEND2);
long length1 = myFile2.length();
dos.writeLong(length);

fis = new FileInputStream(myFile1);
bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
int theByte1 = 0;
/*sending second  file */

while((theByte = bis.read()) != -1) bos.write(theByte);
bis.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on the GUI side code you are sending two files But  during sending the  second file

```
 fis = new FileInputStream(myFile1);
```

you have made fileinputstream to myFIle1 on both the times , change it to myFile2 on the second time